# How to make Kivy Checkbox a square

Tags: python, kivy

Is there any way to make a kivy checkbox from a circle checkbox to a square checkbox?

This is my code for my current checkbox:

```
        CheckBox:
            group: 'check'
            id : chk
            pos: 240,300
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `group` with a `CheckBox`, it changes to a circle. You can subclass `CheckBox` to avoid that behavior:

```
<MyCheckBox@CheckBox>:
    canvas:
        Clear:
        Color:
            rgba: self.color
        Rectangle:
            source: self._checkbox_image
            size: sp(32), sp(32)
            pos: int(self.center_x - sp(16)), int(self.center_y - sp(16))
```

This creates a `MyCheckBox` widget that does not display the circle behavior even when `group` is used. The above `kv` just defines the `canvas` by using `Clear` to remove the `CheckBox` `canvas` instructions, and replacing them with basically the same instructions, but eliminating the `group` reference.